# Ionic API Calls, Duplicate API on Route Changes mixed with willViewEnter

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic app, which will be deployed to mobile. I am refreshing the data in both a route subscription from ngOnInit, as well as a hard-coded refresh call in ionViewWillEnter. And as you would expect, I get duplicate API calls all the time.

The reason I'm subscribing to the route change, is so I can pick up if someone uses the menu to change the route, but it goes to the same component, just a different :parameter (such as a view that shows any product, but the parameter says which one).

I'm thinking I can just remove everything from ionViewWillEnter and the problem will be solved, but I have a hunch I'll be adding it back after the first wave of testing, and get stuck in the same place.

Can anyone with more experience comment on this?

Edit: Added Code as suggested through comment:

```
ionWillViewEnter() {
 // Component was re-used, currentProduct probably has value already. 
 if (this.currentProduct != undefined) { 
 this.refreshData();
 }
}

ngOnInit() {
   this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
     if (params['product'] != null) {
        this.currentProduct = params['product'];
        this.refreshData();         
      }
}
```

Comment: Please post code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you can try with a resolver that will give the data to your component base on the route parameters. Check : https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

Comment: Also, you can use only the ionViewWillEnter as it is called after ngOnInit.

Comment: uKioops: I found that if I only use ionViewWillEnter, re-use of the component seems to prevent any refreshes if the route changes but it lands on the same component.